# re-queue all messages from one queue to another with pika

Tags: python, queue, rabbitmq, pika

I need to loop though all the messages in the queue for the callback and then close the call back. I need it to stop consuming once the queue is empty. 
So I'm writing the messages from one queue to another queue.

`creds = pika.PlainCredentials(app.config['mq.user'], app.config['mq.pass'])
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
                host=app.config['mq.host'],
                credentials=creds))
        connection2 = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
                host=app.config['mq.host'],
                credentials=creds))`

```
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel2 = connection2.channel()

Def requeue_callback(ch, method, properties, body):
try:
    msg = json.loads(body)
    ch2.basic_publish(exchange='',
                      routing_key=base_queue+'.request',
                      body = msg['orig_msg'])
finally:
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag)

channel.basic_consume(requeue_callback,
                  queue=base_queue+'.error')

channel.start_consuming()
```

*Alternatively I could find the number of messages in a queue and then consume that specific number. In that case how would I re-queue a specific number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your callback function you can to declare queue with `passive=True`, then use result to get message count.

For example:

```
>>> ch = rabbit.connection.channel()
>>> method = ch.queue_declare('sandbox', passive=True)
>>> method.method.message_count
23
>>>
```

Then check if this number is 0.